# azure B2C provides different type of keys for same policy on different b2c accounts (used for staging)

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

We have 4 different b2c accounts to reflect our different stages.(dev,test,preprod,prod). We deploy the custom policies with jenkins and they are be the same (except for the tenant). In dev and preprod I get for the jwk

```
{
  "keys": [
    {"kid":"cryDHrls_bD7W0G0PEd-4k61TsW-aQmprRc4hxVwLEo","use":"sig","kty":"RSA","e":"AQAB","n":"uXyfO_YvhkxIhk3k3cFmvigl9tcewAaohABpukYsUceakNOzGHSvnT0uAX7-0k_xa5PKA7pgskgQYeN70iUw4BIlbaBISpJKZpiY0wv3H23EbrTt6aUV7rvBYH2UoJ2LoBhsQaqM3Wer7wD8TjPT11azPUSOyuS7Ju5NZeG723kIxNFFb0H4_eHsHeFkxktxXxmcVMDDlWIpq85PCJepdf-KtXbWLl3QfLa5CG6rTd3R6p53CDX0ktg1weNqlcg3W05D_zBJ9_QLP-9tJKqQIoN4L-5aAlIvzcM2rQpjljHqxg11c7p4ecqqg8IBoh7Ob5BgE1lPpKdcNDdpW6g2vQ"}
  ]
```

and

```
{
  "keys": [
    {"kid":"whWP-xfUz5r-B2hkKRuttLaF17jNQWPjKvvt0t6RnXs","use":"sig","kty":"RSA","e":"AQAB","n":"l3XZpxOy3Aj5OAssunKXMB2RMLcZqG5Ilch5SibtHvUF4Lg-OAf-8HImVwcVljPRXXcRe3yb9AWMon60X3TESkpRFwM-JZv70r0pZgaI-UPRjBo8bI_T9JlbNc9-Eyh68aGX09go7prlshQCdt4QRbueNCMRtogU0xcKUh5JnGWgDlqptCFgTQETunPBdaqASEMzW4_E7iPhcK017bg2Y_kc52AOQNlx27gjWv9G1ql7tmtUGdV0FfjBdBA4wxi6foHmk_7Akj99DdxI7B0QTxbUh1ZSeOYBVPyFSrGir4oGzK4Tn50D9R_W4LYJRqdZIB0zUrAwSyU3uLWg4b9pDQ"}
  ]
}
```

respectively. But on our test account I get

```
{
  "keys": [
    {"kid":"Gwsav9XG6fIaFHmzxMUZ0AvF_VpKCOsI_8qmQ53-uO4","use":"sig","kty":"oct"}
  ]
}
```

I didn't find any option to set/influence this and our java lib (auth0) for checking jwt doesn't work with that kind of jwk.

Comment: Can you confirm that you're getting the keys from the jwk_uris field retrieved from the .well-known endpoint of your tenant? Keep in mind that the keys are managed by Microsoft and may be specific to the tenant *and* policy.

Comment: How did you get these keys? I just checked and the B2C endpoint returns a slightly different format. In particular, my records always have the nbf attribute.

Comment: I should not give out the b2c tenant name (all 3 are different of couzrse like contagodev, contagotest..) and i hit this endpoint to get the jwk

https://<tenant>.b2clogin.com/<tenant>.onmicrosoft.com/discovery/v2.0/keys?p=b2c_1a_my_signin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new tenant, but actually found the answer to my own question. When you create the TokenSigningKeyContainer key, make sure you choose RSA.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may be connecting to the wrong endpoint to get the key.

Normally you should first connect to the .well-know endpoint for your tenant and policy, e.g. https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/tenant_name.onmicrosoft.com/policy_name/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration. From the response you then retrieve the jwks_uri, which is something like https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/tenant_name.onmicrosoft.com/policy_name/discovery/v2.0/keys. Note that this is different than the endpoint you gave us in your comments, so this may be your issue. The correct key endpoint includes the "te" in the URL, and the policy is part of the URL, not passed in the query string.

Comment: thx for your quick reply - i didn't know that, unfortunatley those endpoints lead to the same result i posted above i.e. the one endpoint has still the same. it happens only for one tenant and it is the same for all policies. I suspect there is a tenant-wide setting for this which is different.

Comment: To my knowledge, the keys are controlled by MS. It's strange that the type is "oct", this means "octet" and according to RFC 7518 is used for *symmetric* keys, so it's presumed the client already knows the key (it's a shared secret). Have you tried to create a new B2C tenant? It should be free... I suspect you created that tenant in a slightly different way, or something went wrong at creation time.

Comment: thx again for your reply - this might well be the case - I will try and create a new tenant and see if I find the settings.